# TimeSpan.ParseExact("000000.000", "hhmmss.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); Input string was not in a correct format C#?

Tags: c#

I want to setup two TimeSpans lasttimestamp and time and set them to 0 like this :

```
        TimeSpan lasttimestamp = TimeSpan.ParseExact("000000.000","hhmmss.fff",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact("000000.000", "hhmmss.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

then in a later while loop i want to set timestamp to a value in a log file in in the format hhmmss.fff and subtract it from the lasttimestamp timespan :

```
TimeSpan timestamp = TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitline[1], "hhmmss.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 time = timestamp.Subtract(lasttimestamp);
```

how ever it does not like the .fff part in the formating resulting in "Input string was not in a correct format" ?

I have tried with DateTime but get cannot convert TimeSpan to DateTime when performing the subtraction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `.` in your format like `@"hhmmss\.fff"`:

```
 TimeSpan lasttimestamp = TimeSpan.ParseExact(@"000000.000", 
                            @"hhmmss\.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But, you should use [`TimeSpan.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set up zero time stamp like:

```
TimeSpan lastTimeSpanZero = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Both will return same value.

```
(lasttimestamp == lastTimeSpanZero) == true
```

Later on, in your parsing escape the `.`.

```
TimeSpan timestamp = TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitline[1], 
                          @"hhmmss\.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks works a treat i did try the escape before the period but did not put the @ infront :)